# Why does the while loop never end?

Tags: php

Please have a look at this code snippet -

`while ($row = $getForums_data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

I've tried different variations of the above but it keeps putting me in the loop of death. Can anybody tell what is wrong here? The query isn't wrong because I tested it and it works fine. But the while loop doesn't end.

Comment: use `$getForums_data->fetch`

Comment: Where did you see that you have to use a `while` loop with `fetchAll()`? The manual surely doesn't state that. Did you read the function synopsis in the manual at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetchAll()` fetches all rows from your result set so if there are results, it will return a non-empty array each time you call it.

If you just want to get the results row-by-row until there are no more (and the loop stops...), you need:

```
while ($row = $getForums_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Or you fetch all rows into a variable and use a `foreach()` to loop over that variable.